# não aparece nada na tela quando add o router

Tags: javascript, html, react, react-native

quando eu tiro o Route, tudo funciona normalmente, ja tentei copiar o codigo do prof e da o mesmo erro, e preciso criar outro route pra agir como uma pag diferente, eu ja isntalei o npm do react-router-dom, e também quando tento importar o route sozinho ele importa do react-router

```
import React, { useState }  from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";




import Tasks from "./components/tasks";
import AddTask from "./components/addTask";
import Header from "./components/header";

import './App.css'
const App = ()=>{

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      id:1,
      title:"estudar programação",
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id:2,
      title:"ler livros",
      completed: true
    }

  ]);

  const handleTasksAddition = (taskTitle)=>{
      const newTask = [...tasks,{
        title:taskTitle,
        id: uuidv4(),
        completed:false
      }]

      setTasks(newTask);
  }

  const handleTaskDeletion = (taskId) =>{
    const newTasks = tasks.filter( task => task.id !== taskId)

    setTasks(newTasks)
  }

  const handleTaskClick = (taskId)=>{
    const newTask = tasks.map(task => {
      if(task.id === taskId)return{...task, completed: !task.completed}

      return task
      
    })

    setTasks(newTask)
  }
  return (
  <Router>
          <div className="container">
           <Header/>
           <Route
                    path="/"
                    exact
                    render={() => (
                        <div>
                            <AddTask handleTasksAddition={handleTasksAddition} />
                            <Tasks
                                tasks={tasks}
                                handleTaskClick={handleTaskClick}
                                handleTaskDeletion={handleTaskDeletion}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )}
                />
          </div>

    
  </Router>
  )
  
}

export default App;
```

esse é o codigo, e o problema aparentemente ta aqui no final.

Answer (score 0):

Estou com um problema similar, mas pesquisando na internet descobri que a nova versão do router (v6) muda algumas coisas, como por exemplo:

- O antigo switch recebeu algumas mudanças e agora se chama Router. E também todos os Routes precisam estar dentro dele.
- A propriedade `exact` não é mais necessária (ou não exite?).

Então é necessário importar o Routes:
`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";`

E coloca-lo entre o Router e o Route:

```
return (
    <Router>
        <div className="container">
            <Header />
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    render={() => (
                        <div>
                            <AddTask handleTasksAddition={handleTasksAddition} />
                            <Tasks
                                tasks={tasks}
                                handleTaskClick={handleTaskClick}
                                handleTaskDeletion={handleTaskDeletion}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )}
                />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    </Router>
)
```

Isso, claro, se estiver usando a versão 6. Espero ter ajudado.